# Adding a printer with Powershell

Tags: powershell, printing

I'm trying to use Powershell to automate installation of a Sharp MX-3070N printer. I can successfully add the printer with:

```
Add-PrinterPort -Name "printer3" -PrinterHostAddress "10.65.20.50"

Add-PrinterDriver -Name "Microsoft IPP Class Driver"

Add-Printer -Name "sharpmx3070n" -DriverName "Microsoft IPP Class Driver" -PortName "printer3"
```

Problem is, I'm not then able to change most printing preferences (colour, quality etc). Only orientation can be set.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TaE6.png

But if I add the printer manually via clicking in the "printers and scanners" settings, I get the full selection of preferences.

I can't see any difference between my Powershell-created printer and my mouse-click-created printer other than the port type (TCP/IP vs IPP - would that possibly affect being able to set preferences?).

[image: screenshots of the problem]

Comment: When you install it with GUI the driver may be more specific than IPP. This is probably a Sharp Driver. You may first install it with GUI and play with `Get-PrinterProperty` and `Get-PrintConfiguration` to see what you can do. It is possible also that some properties may be accessible only with WMI (`*-WMI* or *-CIM*).

Comment: The output that I posted of get-printer seems to suggest that the IPP driver is in use for the GUI-created printer (unless you're suggesting there's a more specific variant of the IPP driver in use?). `Get-PrinterProperty` wasn't much help but `Get-PrintConfiguration` did throw out columns for the preferences I'm interested in. Again though, identical output for both the GUI-created and Powershell-created printers.

Comment: Also, I can use `Set-PrintConfiguration` on my Powershell-created printer to switch printing to black and white, but then test prints still come out in colour. If I do the same via Powershell to a GUI-created printer that has a visible GUI black and white option, it does then switch to black and white.

Comment: Ok, I thank it was the output of a PowerShell created printer. But if both PS and GUI driver are the same ... For my home TCP/IP printer I've a more specific driver that's why I wondered.
Set-PrintConfiguration require administrator credentials so for me this should modify the configuration system scope and not only for one user ... I don't know currently ...

Answer (score 1):

OK it was indeed driver-related (or at least I fixed it by changing to the proper drivers). For anyone who happens to be using Ansible / Powershell to automate the installation of this printer:

```
- name: install Sharp MX3070N driver
  win_shell: pnputil /add-driver "C:\sharp-mx3070n\su0emenu.inf" /install

- name: add printer port
  win_shell: Add-PrinterPort -Name "printer3" -PrinterHostAddress "yourprintersIP"

- name: add printer driver
  win_shell: Add-PrinterDriver -Name "SHARP MX-3070N PCL6" # if this string is not known, grab from .inf file

- name: add printer
  win_shell: Add-Printer -Name "sharpmx3070n" -DriverName "SHARP MX-3070N PCL6" -PortName "printer3"

- name: black and white printing
  win_shell: Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName "sharpmx3070n" -Color 0 # B&W

- name: single-sided printing
  win_shell: Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName "sharpmx3070n" -DuplexingMode 'OneSided'
```