Configure printers using powershell
I recently started using powershell and was trying to automate the process of installing and configuring the printers in the office.
Installing the printer is working fine, but when i try to set the print color to black and white using Set-PrintConfiguration it changes the color parameter to false but doesnt change anything in the print settings.
Here's the code:
$printersMapped = Get-Printer "Kyocera PRETO" 
if (-not $printersMapped){
    Pnputil /add-driver "E:\PROGRAMAS\IMPRESSORAS\KYOCERA\TASKalfa 2553ci\PrnDrv\KXDriver\64bit\OEMSETUP.inf"
    Add-PrinterDriver -Name "Kyocera TASKalfa 2553ci KX" -InfPath "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\oemsetup.inf_amd64_7854780b77774b14\oemsetup.inf"
    Add-PrinterPort -Name "Porta ip" -PrinterHostAddress ***.***.**.***
    Add-Printer -DriverName "Kyocera TASKalfa 2553ci KX" -Name "Kyocera PRETO" -PortName "Porta ip"
    Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName "Kyocera PRETO" -Color $false
}else{
    Write-Host "Printer Kyocera PRETO already installed"
}

I also want to change a setting to enable job acounting and use a especific acount id, but cant find anything that helps with that.

Is there a way to do this?

Sorry, but pnputil is not (necessarily) called from  [tag:powershell])

This answer might be useful, did you check it?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69725813/724039

@Luuk That's the only way to do it.

More info needed like Get-PrintConfiguration -Printername "Kyo..."  | Format-List Color before and after the Set-PrintConfiguration...` (no  pictures) needed.)

Hard for us to understand that image in that language (this site expects to see things in English!), but it looks like you're on the Printer Configuration tab. This tab refers to settings for the printer device itself, and not settings for the driver or workstation. Instead, you need to either look on the General tab under the Preferences... button or on the Advanced tab under the Printing Defaults... button. If you check here, you may find one or both of them defaults to black and white, depending on whether your run that line in the script.
As for the job accounting, this part of the interface is customized by the device driver. It's different for each manufacture and sometimes also for different device lines within the manufacturer. Therefore, there's not enough information to provide settings for this with the base PowerShell library. Your manufacturer may provide a Powershell module you can add that can do this, or you may need to trace down what files or registry settings the user interface modifies and have your powershell file update that diretly.

Im aware that the screenshot is not of the driver workstation but it was only to show the box that i wanted checked and the id i wanted to add (thats why I posted it in portuguese).
If you think it would be helpfull i can add a screenshot of the driver workstation

So if I understand correctly, your problem is that setting the color with Set-PrintConfiguration doesn't actually change it in the print settings. If so, you can try this superuser answer. Basically, you need to remove the printer and add it again, then set the color again.
Here is the complete code to do it:
$PrinterName = 'Kyocera PRETO'

$printer = Get-Printer -Name $PrinterName
Remove-Printer -Name $PrinterName
Add-Printer -DriverName $printer.DriverName -Name $PrinterName -PortName $printer.PortName

Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $PrinterName -Color $false

